# How to incorporate hour to Y-M-D DateTimeIndex in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas time series dataframe. My index is a DatetimeIndex with format Year-Month-Day. I have another column with the hour.

```
Date,hour
2004-10-03, 18.00.00,
2004-10-03, 19.00.00,
...
2005-04-18,05.00.00
```

How can I make my index to incorporate the hour also, like the following:

```
Date,hour
2004-10-03 18, 18.00.00,
2004-10-03 19, 19.00.00,
...
2005-04-18 05,05.00.00
```

Comment: `df.set_index(['Date', 'hour'], inplace=True)` ?

Comment: I would like to have just one index with a format like Y-M-D H. Also, there is the problem that my 'hour' column has the format '18.00.00' so it's not parsed properly with the method you suggested.

Comment: do `df['hour'] = df['hour'].str.replace('.', ':')` the `df['hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'])`

Answer (score 0):

```py
# example dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['2004-10-03','18.00.00'], ['2004-10-03','19.00.00']], columns=['Date', 'hour'])

# replace the . with : so you don't get parsing error
df['hour'] = df['hour'].str.replace('.', ':')

# convert to_timedelta and to_datetime
df['hour'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['hour'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# combine Date and hour
df['combined'] = df['Date'] + df['hour']

# set the combined as index
df.set_index(['combined'], inplace=True)
```

```
combined              Date          hour
2004-10-03 18:00:00   2004-10-03    0 days 18:00:00
2004-10-03 19:00:00   2004-10-03    0 days 19:00:00
```

NOTE: you can drop `Date` and `hour` column if ou don't need

```py
df.drop(['Date', 'hour'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```